# Swift HTTP request on a Unix domain socket

Tags: swift, macos, sockets, http, named-pipes

I decided to learn Swift and for that I though I will build a small application, but I stuck at the second step.

I need to create an HTTP request on a UNIX domain socket (named pipe) but I spent hours of searching and could not find any example or library which would support that.

The closest I've found is [PerfectlySoft/Perfect-CURL](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-CURL) which uses libcurl under the hood and could be modified to support UNIX domain sockets (by setting the `CURLOPT_UNIX_SOCKET_PATH`) but that does not compile on macOS.

Could somebody please show me an example how to perform an HTTP request on a UNIX domain socket using Swift?

Comment: Have you checked Alamofire? The best networking for iOS in swift

Comment: Yes, they don't support it.

Comment: you should check https://github.com/IBM-Swift/BlueSocket